# calling a constructor fails in JNI Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a constructor from my JNI Android code; but somehow it fails with the following exception..
I am sure I am missing something really small ; but I am not able to figure out ... can anyone please point out ?

```
 02-14 16:56:56.689: W/dalvikvm(397): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
 02-14 16:56:56.710: W/dalvikvm(397):              in Lpv/ndk/Employee;.createWithAge (I)Lpv/ndk/Employee; (GetMethodID)

 02-14 16:56:56.710: W/dalvikvm(397): Pending exception is:
 02-14 16:56:56.710: I/dalvikvm(397): Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError;: pv.ndk.Employee;
 02-14 16:56:56.723: I/dalvikvm(397):   at pv.ndk.Employee.createWithAge(Native Method)

 02-14 16:56:56.740: I/dalvikvm(397): Caused by:
 02-14 16:56:56.740: I/dalvikvm(397): Ljava/lang/ClassNotFoundException;: pv.ndk.Employee; in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/pv.ndk-2.apk]
```

Here is my code :

Employee class has 2 constructors and a method to return the age

```
Employee()
Employee(int age)
int getAge();
```

suprisingly when I invoke the method getAge()..the call goes through and fetches the age... But when I try to call the "Employee constructor" and then try to getAge() this exception is thrown...

somehow It is not able to find the class:
I have tried with all the possiblities I came across for GetObjectClass()

this works ; when I pass the Employee object in the call

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_pv_ndk_Employee_getAgeC(JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject, jobject employeeObject) 
{
jclass employeeClass = env->GetObjectClass(employeeObject);
jmethodID midGetName = env->GetMethodID(employeeClass, "getAge", "()I");
int age =  env->CallIntMethod(employeeObject, midGetName);
//other code
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK ; I am not sure why it is not able to find the class..
I have tried with "Lpv/ndk/Emploee" "LEmployee" "pv/ndk/Employee" .. and even tried with the following approach:

```
jclass localRefCls = env->FindClass("pv/ndk/Employee");
jclass clazzEmployee = (_jclass*)env->NewGlobalRef(localRefCls);
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_pv_ndk_Employee_createWithAge(JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject, jint age) {
jclass employeeClass = env->FindClass("pv/ndk/Employee");
jmethodID midConstructor = env->GetMethodID(employeeClass, "<init>", "(I)V"); // BOOM SCREWED HERE .. !!
}
```

But everytime my code comes to env->GetMethodID - the vm Aborts ...

Comment: Can you check if employeeClass variable is not NULL?

Comment: I don't understand your second code snippet. What scope does localRefCls have and when is it assigned?

Comment: @Martins : employeeClass is not NULL

Comment: @Ruben : the second code snippet was according to one of the solution for the similar situation.. where it was suggested to create a globalReference.. and delete the localReference...but anyways that did not help either

jclass localRefCls = env->FindClass("pv/ndk/Employee");
jclass clazzEmployee = (_jclass*)env->NewGlobalRef(localRefCls);
env->DeleteLocalRef(localRefCls);

Answer (score 0):

surprisingly the same code works today :)

probably it had to do with the way I was deploying the code... I believed that "auto build" should have taken care of it... Really sorry for creating confusion here regarding a working code snippet... I am new to NDK and JNI development ...

This definately works

```
jclass employeeClass = env->FindClass("pv/ndk/Employee");
//constructor call depicted by <init> and it's parameters (I) and return type V
jmethodID midConstructor = env->GetMethodID(employeeClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
```

I think the reason might have to do with the "native shared-library" not getting deployed after new modification... These are the steps I used to follow :
[1] I re-built the "Shared-library" with the modification ; using the "ndk-build"
__[2] Then I deploy the android project on my device

but seems Eclipse caches the "library" ??? [ please correct me if I am wrong ]
Hence the changes were taken into account...

Solution : [ possibly ]

[1] I rebuilt the library __ [2] I cleaned the whole project __ [3] then deployed the project on device...

Answer (score 0):

FindClass method needs full class signature.
Note:if you have any inner classes / will not work,you have to use $
for example if your package name is A.B.C and your main class name is D and your subclass name is E then you have to use FindClass("LA/B/C/D$E;");